# Shell Scripting to make an executable file a native command

Tags: shell

I wrote a shell script named cleanup in linux. I am new to it and I am learning from a book. It told me to save the file in /usr/local/bin/ but when I run the following command I get this error:

> ```
> $ cp cleanup /usr/local/bin/
> ```
>
> cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/cleanup': Permission
>   denied

I don't know how to write the file in that folder. Here is the code of cleanup:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Proper header for a Bash script.
# Cleanup, version 2
# Run as root, of course.
# Insert code here to print error message and exit if not root.

# Variables are better than hard-coded values.
cat ./hello > cleaning
echo "Logs cleaned up."
exit 
# The right and proper method of "exiting" from a script.
# A bare "exit" (no parameter) returns the exit status
#+ of the preceding command.
```

Can you help me copy the file to /usr/local/bin/
I am doing this because its an executable file and if I put it in the above mentioned folder, I can run the name of the file like a native command.
I working in the terminal of ubuntu...if it makes a difference, please tell me.

Comment: Do you know what “permission denied” means? (serious question)

Comment: You're probably better off putting it in a local directory (such as /home/you/bin) and putting that directory in your PATH, that way you don't have to worry about getting into /usr/local/bin, or creating random new commands for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/usr/local/bin/` directory in linux is a protected directory.It holds a number of executables and hence must be protected from files that may pose a security issue.

Hence the write permissions to the directory is restricted to the root user only.

You can get root privileges by using the `sudo` command.Use sudo in front of `cp` command, like `sudo cp ....`.For this you must be a admin user

If you are not an admin user,you will get a error message and you must have to login as root or any other admin user to perform the copy.

After you copy your file,be sure to check the permissions of the file.It must have execute permissions.You can assign execute permissions using `sudo chmod +x <filename>`.

Comment: thank you so much...it finally works.

Comment: could I ask you something else too?

Comment: I have a folder in which I need to clean some files and not all of them. So in the script, I go to the folder I need to make changes in. Then somehow I want to take in all the names of the folders and files included in the folder. Then I want to check for each file if it is a log file and clean it. If it is not a file, but a folder, then go into the folder and do the same thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: if your log files have some kind of common extension, say .log,then you can do,`find . -type f | grep \.log$ | xargs  <clearing script taking filename as argument>`

Comment: okay, that makes sense and what about the folders? How do I know if it is a folder or not.

Comment: when using `find`,you need'nt bother about that.It navigates recursuively into folders.

Comment: thanks a lot rjv, that was a lot
Have a nice day :)